# Parellel execution on multiple hosts

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have the following data in my database.

```
LOGANAME    DOWNLOADED
```

LOGNAME field tells me what logs to download and process and DOWNLOADED is a flag that I set to true when I have successfully downloaded the log. Since there are a lot of logs to download I wish to to run the process of downloading and flagging as downloaded over multiple hosts. So basically I make a database query to get all the logname where DOWNLOADED='false' and then download them and set DOWNLOADED='true' . Now when I run the same process over multiple hosts all of them download all the logs . Is there some way to code this to make sure that the hosts don't download the same logs?

Answer (score 1):

Before downloading any log from a process, mark the `DOWNLOADED`  flag to `true` by firing an `Update` SQL

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET DOWNLOADED = `true` where DOWNLOADED = `false` AND LOGNAME = LOG_NAME_TO_DOWNLOAD
```

and check the output of `UPDATE` statement that how many rows have been affected. If rows affected count is greater then 0 then continue downloading the logs from that process otherwise skip that logfile and process another.

I am considering that `LOGNAME` to be unique that is this columns is `Primary Key` or having all the distinct values.